# Meteor application - Stuck at "Starting your app" when trying to run

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor 1.3.1 project and I try to run in IntelliJ Webstorm on Windows 10.

The problem is that when I run my application everything works fine up until all the packages are loaded, then the program gets stuck at "Starting your app". So I get the "*Started proxy*" message and all the packages load properly.

I can also mention that I have a Macbook on which the project runs just fine. So it feels like the problem is related to some configuration on my Windows machine...

The image below shows where the terminal gets stuck after running `meteor --verbose`.

[image: screenshot of my terminal after running meteor --verbose]

There is no error message or anything, the terminal just keeps saying "*Starting your app*".

I have tried the following with no result:

- running `meteor reset` command
- reinstalling meteor.
- turning my firewall off in case it would cause some problem...
- creating a new project and running it (the same problem occurs for all projects).
- Create and run a new project from Windows command line. (the same thing happens, gets stuck at "*starting your app*").

I greatly appreciate any suggestions to how to solve this problem! I've been bashing my head to the keyboard for quite a while and haven't managed to find a solution online either...

Comment: Thanks, `meteor reset` was what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

I faced with such problem today on windows 8
This helped me : [Meteor App not able to connect to MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776143/meteor-app-not-able-to-connect-to-mongodb)

set MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sample

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove .meteor\local\db\METEOR-PORT before running meteor

Answer (score 0):

Take a look `.meteor/local/db` dir -- check if there is a `mongod.lock` file.

If there is, check its contents -- it should be empty.

If its not empty, it means MongoDB wasn't `gracefully` shutdown or something.

Try deleting this file (or deleting its contents) and running Meteor again.

`rm -f .meteor/local/db/mongod.lock
meteor`

Comment: Looking at your answer I deleted the mongod.lock file from all of the projects on my system but still my app is stuck at Starting your app. Any idea what is the issue here ??

Comment: @PiyushKumar Nope, it worked for me. A more severe approach would be to remove the whole `.meteor` folder, but that will RESET your project and database as well (not ideal).

Answer (score 0):

Run your CMD as administrator. It might work.
I had the same problem. it was because meteor mongo db was not able to connect. or if this doesn't work. run

> meteor mongo localhost:[mongo_db_port]

you will know which port your app is using for mongo db in
file

> your_app_name.meteor\local\db\METEOR-PORT

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. What happens is that meteor couldn't start the mini mongo after it has already been initiated once. (First run always worked fine)

The solution was simply to remove meteor and install it using [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) (as described on the [meteor website](https://www.meteor.com/install))