# Meteor, it hangs at "Starting your app" when trying run my new app

Tags: meteor

Meteor 1.3.x project hangs at “Starting your app” when I trying run my new application on Windows 7

[image]

I don't understand what is the reason for this. Can you help me?

Comment: you got stuck there or what?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor application - Stuck at "Starting your app" when trying to run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36649478/meteor-application-stuck-at-starting-your-app-when-trying-to-run)