# Meteor 1.4.2.3 for Windows. Stuck at “Starting your app”

Tags: meteor

I've installed the latest version of meteor 1.4.2.3 and simply trying to create my first meteor app. The steps are simple but the process keeps looping on "Starting your app".

I've searched for solutions and tried the following with no success: meteor update, changing the port, npm install, meteor reset, uninstall and reinstall.

Stuck at "Starting you app" seems to be a common issue with no consensus on solution.

Please someone help!

Answer (score 1):

Meteor needs quite a bit of memory, if you have less than 8GB it will struggle.

Sometimes just control-c it and starting it again works.

Sometimes it needs a

```
meteor reset
```

Another thing you can do is remove

```
<project-dir>/.meteor/local
```

Usually the problem only rears its head once in a while

Comment: Others claim their app works on 1GB. 
"The bottleneck for most Meteor apps seems to be CPU and not RAM, so scaling horizontally is a must. You can add all the RAM you want, but it won’t help your app. Lack of CPU is what’s going to overload your app and you can only get more CPU power by making use of multiple CPUs (or multiple servers)."
https://medium.freecodecamp.com/first-experiences-scaling-a-meteor-app-14a48e62a4af#.rxj6abmh2

Comment: Please provide evidence of running meteor in development on 1GB, because my experience says it can't be done. On our project one of the guys has a 2GB macbook air and it struggles, taking minutes to do an incremental build. I have an older (core Duo) Macbook with 8GB of RAM, which copes just fine.

Comment: I have 4GB and I simply created the first app suggested by Meteor, myapp, and I left in run for over an hour. The physical memory under Windows Task Manager displayed ample memory throughout the entire hour. I don't doubt Meteor requires significant memory but this seems excessive.

Comment: There is definitely something wrong, 4GB should be enough to do it much quicker than that, and if you are not short of RAM, that is not the problem. Did you do as I suggested?

Comment: Yes, I tried meteor reset along with a fresh new install. I removed the following folder myapp/.meteor/local but it simply creates a new local folder when meteor attempts to run myapp.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest now is going back to a previous version of Meteor. The Windows port sometimes gets issues like that, as Mac/Linux is where most of the development work happens

Comment: I plan on trying a Linux virtual machine in Windows. Hopefully that's the solution. 
Thank you for all the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I met this issue too. And Meteor stuck suddenly, it was working fine a day before. I tried everything. Uninstalling,reseting meteor, updating meteor, updating npm, meteor npm cache clean,Registry editing etc. Nothing helped. Then,

I updated my Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and it was working again.

Edit: try this method first.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46133529/3959840

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded meteor for Windows V 1.5.2. In my case I did not have Mongo DB installed.

I downloaded it from [here](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center?jmp=nav#community) and in cmd I set the MONGO_URL=' ' and boom it started my app.

Hope this helps someone :).